# android fragment scenario crashes during snackbar creation

Tags: android, android-fragments, testing, android-fragmentscenario

I've got android application. I'm writing test using fragment scenario to test my fragment. My test is simple and looks like this:

```
FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(ShoppingPlanningFragment.class);
...
onView(withId(R.id.buttonRemove)).perform(click());
```

So I'm clicking some button and when this button is clicked snackbar is make like this:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.planning_mode_layout), msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

But I'm getting following error:

> androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single
> click - At Coordinates: 809, 1949 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with
> id is com.gitlab.robert.cebula.expirydate:id/buttonRemove'.     at
> androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:5)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:25)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:36)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:106)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:43)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:94)
> at
> com.example.expirydate.shoppingfragment.planningfragment.ShoppingPlanningFragmentTest.clickingRemove_shouldRemovePlanningItem(ShoppingPlanningFragmentTest.java:28)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
> androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:154)
> at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)     at
> org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)    at
> androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
> at
> androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:395)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2074)
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41:
> Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41:
> Error inflating class android.widget.Button Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)   at
> com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)  at
> com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:165)
> at
> com.example.expirydate.shoppingfragment.planningfragment.ShoppingPlanningFragment.onRemoveButtonClicked(ShoppingPlanningFragment.java:106)
> at
> com.example.expirydate.shoppingfragment.planningfragment.ShoppingPlanningFragment.lambda$uAFpgVG-8MPel7g8tIF4mCnD_tU(Unknown
> Source:0)     at
> com.example.expirydate.shoppingfragment.planningfragment.-$$Lambda$ShoppingPlanningFragment$uAFpgVG-8MPel7g8tIF4mCnD_tU.onClick(Unknown
> Source:2)     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)   at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)   at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:53)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:155)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:149)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:53)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:122)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:117)
> at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:27)     at
> androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:21)     at
> androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:3)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:23)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:16)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:65)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:15)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
> at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
> com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve
> attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300ac a=-1}     at
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:538)
> at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1212)   at
> android.widget.Button.(Button.java:172)     at
> android.widget.Button.(Button.java:147)     at
> android.widget.Button.(Button.java:123)     ... 42 more

If I comment snackbar creation everything works as expected. What's the problem here and how could I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

> The view used to make the snackbar.  This should be contained within
> the view hierarchy you want to display the  snackbar. Generally it can
> be the view that was interacted with to trigger  the snackbar, such as
> a button that was clicked, or a card that was swiped.

```
val contextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.context_view)

Snackbar.make(contextView, R.string.text_label, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show()
```

The important point in the **error** stack.

```
#41: Error inflating class android.widget.Button Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
```

Please check the xml code.

Comment: The xml is fine, when I run the app everything works as expected. The only problem is when using Fragment Scenario :/

Answer (score 0):

FragmentScenario tests your fragment in *isolation*, and it is also isolated from its host activity. It means, it doesn't launch your host activity, instead it launches an **EmptyFragmentActivity**. Thus when you call:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.planning_mode_layout)
```

It can't find that view, because it doesn't use your host activity.

Solution: You either change the structure of your app to make the fragment independent from its host activity, or you don't test this behavior with FragmentScenario.